# Problems with Deleting something in my binary search tree

Tags: javascript

This is a Binary Tree I've made.

**The problem:** When i am deleting a data, it doesn't stop running when going from Left to Right, so it only goes in one direction. it deletes properly when it deletes all Left only and also, all Right only.

This runs properly:

```
BST.insert(10);
BST.insert(9);
BST.insert(8);
BST.insert(7);
BST.insert(6);
BST.insert(5);
BST.insert(4);
BST.Delete(4);
```

or

```
BST.insert(10);
BST.insert(11);
BST.insert(12);
BST.insert(13);
BST.insert(14);
BST.Delete(14);
```

but if you run this it stays in the loop like all conditions inside are false

```
BST.insert(10)
BST.insert(5)
BST.insert(8)
BST.insert(7)
BST.insert(6)
BST.insert(5)
BST.Delete(6)
```

You can try it yourself:

```
var BST = (function(){
  // PRIVATE
  var root = null;

  // NODE OBJECT
  var Node = function (data, left, right) {
    this.data  = data;
    this.left  = left;
    this.right = right;
  }    

  // PUBLIC
  return {
    insert: function(data) {
      const node = new Node(data,null, null);

      if (root === null) {
        root = node; 
      } else {
        let current  = root;

        while (true) {
          if (current.data > data) {
            if (current.left === null) {
              current.left = node;
              console.log(root+ "  1");
              break;
            }

            current = current.left;
          } else {
            if (current.right === null) {
              current.right = node;
              console.log(root+ "  2");
              break;
            }
            current = current.right;
          }
        }
      }
    },

    Delete: function(data) {
      if (root === null) {
        return console.log("Nothings in Tree");
      } else if (root.data === data ) {
        root = null;
        return console.log("found values");
      }

      // condition    
      let current = root;

      while (true) {
        //CHECK If a value exist to the left or right
        if (current.data > data) {
          if (current.left === null) {
            return console.log("Could not find value");
          }
        } else if (current.data < data) {
          if (current.right === null) {
            return console.log("Could not find value");
          }
        }

        // if left exist
        if(current.left !== null){
          if (current.left.data === data) { // if found data
            console.log(`${data} has been remove from the node`);
            current.left = null;
            break;
          } else if (current.left.data > data) {
            //MOVE to the left==============
            console.log(current.left.data+ " .Great");          
            current = current.left;// moves to the left
          }
        }

        if (current.right !== null) {
          if (current.right.data === data) {
            console.log(`${data} has been remove from the node`);
            current.right = null; 
            break;          
          } else if (current.right.data < data) {
            //MOVE to the right==============
            console.log(current.right.data +".Less");
            current = current.right;
          }     
        }       
      }
    },

    show: function() {
      console.log(root);
    },

    test: function() {
      console.log("test is working");
    }
  }    
})();
```

Comment: This code gets stuck in an infinite loop and crashes the browser.

Comment: yes that what happen. now why?

Comment: I seems like stack overflow is use just discourage new developers. i already have a -1 for putting up this which no one see to answer. I was just doing this for fun in another language because i got the time now.

Comment: The more work you do to make it easy for us to solve your problem, the more willing we are to help.  Try converting your code to a run-able snippet.  Add a counter variable that exits the ```while(true)``` loop when it's value hits say 100. That way we can actually debug your code without crashing our browser.  Once your code is fixed people generally remove the downvote.

Comment: Ok thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

It appears that i have over look a condition.

```
 // if left exist
    if(current.left !== null){
      if (current.left.data === data) { // if found data
        console.log(`${data} has been remove from the node`);
        current.left = null;
        break;
      } else if (current.left.data > data) {
        //MOVE to the left==============
        console.log(current.left.data+ " .Great");          
        current = current.left;// moves to the left
      }
    }
```

The "else if (current.left.data > data)" should be replace with just "else" same with the right side. The answer is below.

```
var BST = (function(){
            // PRIVATE
            var root = null;

            // NODE OBJECT
            var Node = function (data,left,right){
            this.data   = data;
            this.left   = left;
            this.right  = right;
            }

            /*function currentToNull(current, data){
                if(current === null){ // repeated operation
                    current = data;
                }
            }*/


    // PUBLIC
    return {

        insert: function(data){
                const node = new Node(data,null, null);

                if(root === null){          
                    root = node; 
                }else{

                    let current  = root;
                    while(true){
                    if(current.data > data){
                                if(current.left === null){
                                    current.left = node;
                                console.log(root+ "  1");
                                break;
                                }
                                current = current.left;
                            }else{
                                if(current.right === null){
                                    current.right = node;
                                console.log(root+ "  2");
                                break;
                                }
                                current = current.right;
                            }
                    }
                }           
        },
        Delete: function(data){
                if(root === null){
                    return console.log("Nothings in Tree");
                }
                // condition        
                let current = root, right_leaf, left_leaf;
                    while(true){

                    right_leaf = current.right; // keep track of left
                    left_leaf =current.left;    // keep track of right


                        //CHECK If a value exist to the left or right
                        if(current.data > data){
                                if(left_leaf === null){
                                    return console.log("Could not find value");
                                }
                        }else if(current.data < data){
                                if(right_leaf === null){
                                    return console.log("Could not find value");
                                }
                        } else if(current.data === data){
                            current = null;
                            return console.log("data found");
                        }



                        if(left_leaf !== null){// L Leaf Data exist
                                    if(left_leaf.data === data){ // if found data
                                        console.log(`${data} has been remove from the node`);
                                        current.left = null;
                                        break;
                                    }else if(left_leaf.data > data){ //MOVE to the left======================
                                            console.log(" Move Left of left");                  
                                            current = current.left;// moves to the left
                                    } else if(left_leaf.data < data ){
                                            console.log(" Move Right of left"); 
                                            current = left_leaf;
                                    }                           
                        }

                        if (right_leaf !== null){
                                    if(right_leaf.data === data){ 
                                        console.log(`${data} has been remove from the node`);
                                        right_leaf = null;  
                                        break;                  
                                    }else if(right_leaf.data < data){   //MOVE to the right=======================          
                                                console.log(" Move Right of right"); 
                                                current = right_leaf;
                                        } else if(right_leaf.data > data ){
                                                console.log(" Move Left of right");
                                                current = right_leaf;

                                        }   
                        }



                    }
        }

        ,
        show: function(){
            console.log(root);
        },
        test: function (){
            console.log("test is working");
        }
    }

})();

//show();
```